# XSRF cookie goes missing on Chrome on Android after a while

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, cookies, csrf

I'm making a Tornado + AngularJS web app, with XSRF protection. When I load it on Chrome on my Android device, it works well. PUT and POST requests contain an `_xsrf` cookie, and a matching `X-Xsrftoken` header field. But if I try to use it again some time later, PUT requests fail because the cookie and header field are missing.

The header field [is added by AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection) when the `_xsrf` cookie is present (I set `xsrfCookieName` and `xsrfHeaderName`), so I assume this is due to the cookie being deleted or something - but it has no expiry date. Other cookies such as user ID are not missing. If I log out and log back in again, the `_xsrf` cookie returns and everything works well again.

This is hard to test because I don't know how long it takes for the cookie to disappear, but I'm sure it has happened a few times. I have the app installed on the home screen. Maybe that makes a difference?

System info: Chrome 44 on Android 5.1.1.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

This happened again, but on a client's computer (desktop Chrome). On closer inspection of the cookies, it seems that the `_xsrf` cookie is set to expire with the *session*, while the other cookies, that identify the user, expire far in the future. I'm not sure why the session seems not to expire on my desktop - maybe because I just use the site more. In any case setting the `_xsrf` cookie's expiration date to the same as the credentials' should fix the problem. In Tornado 4.1, this can be done by overriding [`web.RequestHandler.xsrf_token`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/v4.1.0b2/tornado/web.py#L1056) in your own class:

```
@property
def xsrf_token(self):
    token = super().xsrf_token
    self.set_cookie('_xsrf', token, expires_days=30)
    return token
```

This is required because, during log in, `_current_user` is not defined, so the `_xsrf` token [has a default expiry](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/v4.1.0b2/tornado/web.py#L1091) of `None` (expires with the browser session). Just make sure the expiry date is the same as your other cookies.

See also [this Tornado issue](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/865).